# EditText Inside ListView Shows Random value

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have EditText inside ListView for inline editing. The user can modify its value & the values are then stored in the SQLite database.

I am using Custom DataAdapter for populating ListView.

There are 15 rows in the listview. at a time 4 rows are visible, to see other rows scrollbar is used (Up / Down)

**Issue**: 
ListView is loaded for the first time. User writes into the EditText 1,2,3,4 in each EditText.
The Scrollbar is moved down & one by one the user enters data into all the rows.
When the user moves the Scroll bar UP to see the first 4 rows... **the 4th row shows wrong data instead of 4 it shows 14, which is the last value entered by the user** (OR my have some other random value forexample 10/13/11 etc)

In my Custom DataAdapter class i am storing the user input into the datasource when the EditText loses Focus as shown below:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//txtComments is an EditText 
holder.txtComments.setId(position);
holder.txtComments.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (!hasFocus){
        final int position = v.getId();
        final EditText tempComments = (EditText) v;
             // items: the DataSource for the listView
        items.get(position).Comments = tempComments.getText().toString();
    }
    }
});
}
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

I have also tried the TEXTWATCHER but it doest not work for me.

After extensive testing; we found that this issue  occures randomly for example sometimes ExitText11 will show wrong value another time ExitText4 will show wrong value OR both of them will show wrong values & this behaviour changes while moving scrollbar up down.

Comment: In the `getView` method **after** that focus changed listener do you actually use the `Comments` field to restore the `EditText` to the proper value?

Comment: Sorry for late reply its because of Electricity Faluire.

YUP, this logic is correct, correct field is updated. The logic is working fine but for some of the Edittext the logic not works

Comment: Maybe you could try to use a `TextWatcher` instead of a focus change listener.

Comment: The TextWatcher also not works for me!

Comment: I think the answer may be in the rest of your adapter.